# Lazy loading of an richface component

Tags: java, richfaces, components, lazy-loading

I'm trying to 'lazy-load' a richface component. Somehow i cant get it rendered without a page refresh. I would like to avoid a full page refresh.

Situation:

basic page loaded with:

**menuBean.java**

```
private MenuBarComponent getLazyMenuBarComponent() {
    if (lazyMenuBar != null) {
        return lazyMenuBar;
    }
    lazyMenuBar = new MainMenuBarLazy(); // no children
    return lazyMenuBar;
}
```

After pressing on the 'activate menu'-button:

**page.xhtml**

```
<a4j:region id="main-menu-region">
    <h:form  id="mainMenu-form">
        <rich:dropDownMenu  binding="#{menuBarBean.menuBar}" 
                        id="HOOFDMENU" 
                        showEvent="mouseup" 
                        onclick="showMenu();" 
                        styleClass="menu-hdr-btn"
                        hideDelay="3600000"
                        showDelay="0"
                        onshow="onMenuShow();" 
        />
        <a4j:jsFunction name="fetchMenu" action="#{menuBarBean.fetchMenu}"
            render="@region @form HOOFDMENU">       <!-- I THOUGHT THIS SHOULD WORK -->
        </a4j:jsFunction>
    </h:form> 
</a4j:region>

<a4j:jsFunction name="fetchMenu" action="#{menuBarBean.fetchMenu}">
</a4j:jsFunction>

<javascript>
  function displayMenu(){
      #{rich:component('HOOFDMENU')}.show();
  }
</javascript>
```

**menuBean.java**

```
public String fetchMenu() {
        if(currentMenuBar.getChildrenSize() > 1){
            return "";
        }
        showMenuBar = true;
        currentMenuBar = getMenuBarComponent();   // The component gets pointed to the full menu
        return "TRUE";// "RELOAD" triggers a full page refresh and shows the full menu;
    }

public UIComponent getMenuBar() {
    if (currentMenuBar == null) {
        currentMenuBar = getLazyMenuBarComponent();
    }
    menuBarComponent = currentMenuBar.build();  // Here the component gets builded. It is chosen to build it in the getter because in the build there is also a check of the users ROLE, which can be changed on the fly.
    return menuBarComponent;
}
```

**Added after edit**

**javascript.js**

```
function showMenu(){ // gets triggered when pressed on the dropdown component
    fetchMenu();     // triggers the build-full-menu action
    displayMenu();   // sets dropdownbox to show (the menu should show now), I only get the borders of an empty list
}
```

If i press F5 after the menu-activation button is pressed, the full menu gets shown.
If i return in **fetchMenu()** return="RELOAD" the page gets reloaded and also the full menu gets shown.
If i try to rerender the region/form or on HOOFDMENU i dont get any rerendered full menu.

How can i only reload the menu part of the page and not a full page reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely the render happens before the action finishes. Use the @oncomplete to call another jsFunction that does the rendering. I.e.

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="fetch" oncomplete="reload()" />
<a4j:jsFunction name="reload" render="…" />
```

On the other hand:
The fetchmenu function is defined twice and I don't see it being called anywhere.

You shouldn't have any business logic inside the getter, why not call the build() inside the fetchMenu() method?

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with "@region @form .HOOFDMENU", the menu is inside the form that is inside the region. The dot in front of "HOOFDMENU" probably shouldn't be there either.

Comment: I didnt add the button that calls the js:fetchmenu (the js:fetchmenu calls the java:fetchmenu) because i thought it wouldtn be relevant.
I agree about the logic not in the getter, tried to convince our 'senior'. amybe i should do it ;-)
What i tried with the "@region @form .HOOFDMENU" was to show i tried those things (the . was a copy mistake). 
- I tried you solution with the fetch and reload. It didnt work for me. It still shows an empty menu list. After a F5, the full menu is shown though

Comment: It looks like i got it to work. Still need to find out what else i do/did wrong. But the method you gave is valid and correct (when implemented correct)